# ValueChanges is triggered on blur when input is of type Number

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

Unlike other types of HTML inputs, I found it rather surprising that typing into an input of type Number would trigger valueChanges when the input is blurred, as well as clicking on the spinners (the small arrows on the side) would trigger valueChanges twice, is this an expected behavior, or am I missing something?

**Component:**

```js
export class AppComponent {

  textControl = new FormControl();
  numberControl = new FormControl();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.textControl.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
    this.numberControl.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
  }

}
```

**Template:**

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="numberControl">
<input type="number" [formControl]="textControl">
```

Here's Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-material-4xxw5u)

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you mean but this stackblitz, has exactly your code and valueChanges are logging on change / keydown as expected https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rrqwon?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Try pressing on any number within the input of type number and then click outside of that input, you'll see the value has been written to the console twice

Comment: it doesnt happen in @alou's stackblitz

Comment: @alou's look at the demo I've posted in my answer

Comment: oh it's really happening..

Comment: RafiHenig, your angular version is 9 and @alou's version is 10. Both of the demos are actually same code. I think it's an issue in Angular 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12540) which has been already fixed in Angular 10

**[Forked Stackblitz with Angular 10](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-material-azw6c5)**

Prior to this fix Angular [listed to two events](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/97d6d90):

```
host: {
    '(change)': 'onChange($event.target.value)',
    '(input)': 'onChange($event.target.value)',
```

Starting from Angular 10 it listens only for one:

```
host: {
     '(input)': 'onChange($event.target.value)'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks it's an issue in some versions of Angular.
Someone also reported the same issue on Github.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26054

It looks it's fixed in Angular 10 as long as @alon's demo is working.

I believe it isn't a critical issue for you.

However, one simple solution is to use `distinctUntilChanged` operator.

```
this.numberControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: You solution is great, but It gets more complicated when input is nested inside a groupForm where there are more controls, you'll have to implement your own comparison strategy in `distinctUntilChanged`